# Proving isomorphism between a quotient space of continuous functions.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

This is really a follow-up question to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/894101/proving-isomorphism-between-between-a-subspace-and-a-quotient-space) question, in the sense that it arose from that question. You don't need to read that question for this to make sense.

To be proven:

Let $V=\mathcal C[0,1]$ and $W = \{f \in \mathcal C[0,1] : f(t) = 0 \; for \;   0 \le t \le {1 \over 2}\}$ prove that $V/W$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal C[0, {1 \over 2}]$

My work so far:

The strategy I want to use is to make up a $\pi : V \to \mathcal C[0, {1 \over 2}]$ such that $\ker\pi$ = W, that is surjective and then apply the first isomorphism theorem. But the way I want to go about it is a bit shady I think. I simply want to define $$\pi(f(t)) = \begin{cases} 0, & 0 \le t \le {1 \over 2} \\ f(t/2) & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

This is of course surjective with $\ker \pi = W$ and so, by the first isomorphism theorem, I should be done. But it feels weird. It feels like I'm forcing it to work by construction. Does this hold water? What would be a better approach?

As always, any appropriate theory is appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're overthinking it. What is the most straightforward map from $\mathcal{C}([0,1])$ to $\mathcal{C}([0,1/2])$?

Comment: I wanna say $f(t) \mapsto f(t/2)$? I am wrong? I second guess myself for sure. How will that help me?

Comment: More abstractly, if $X\subset Y$, what map $C(Y)\to C(X)$ springs to mind?

Comment: GRRR, frustrated, nothing springs to mind! Maybe simply $f(t) \mapsto f(t)$? I mean of course I can simply map elements to themselves, but then it's like I have nowhere to map a bunch of elements in the domain? Sorry if this is a bit dimwitted...

Comment: If by "Maybe simply $f(t) \mapsto f(t)$" you mean the restriction map $f \mapsto f\lvert_X$, then you have it.

Comment: Hmmm, this is true. I will work through the problem again. I'll get back to you. Thanks

Comment: Consider $\pi: \mathcal C[0,1] \to \mathcal C[0,{1\over2}]$, with $f \mapsto f\restriction_{\mathcal C[0,{1\over2}]}$ Then $\ker \pi$ = W and of course, the map is surjective, since $\mathcal C[0,{1\over2}]$ is $0$ everywhere. And so they are isomorphic. Do I have it? Am I close? Waaaay off?

Comment: You can't restrict f to $\mathcal{C}\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$, the domain of $f$ is $[0,1]$. You restrict it to $\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$. And what you say about the surjectivity doesn't rhyme. You need to show that every continuous function on $\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$ is the restriction of a continuous function on $[0,1]$.

Comment: This is getting ridiculous. Yeah, you're right, I mean of course $f \mapsto f\restriction_{[0,1/2]}$, I'm not sure how this is supposed to help me, what am I missing? I keep thinking about the kernel, but the kernel is just the 0-function in $\mathcal C[0,1]$, no? Should I try to establish a morphism $V/W \to \mathcal C[0,1/2]$ directly or what? What don't I understand?

Comment: No, the kernel of the restriction is precisely $W$. The condition $f(t) = 0 \text{ for } 0 \leqslant t \leqslant \frac{1}{2}$ can also be written as $f\lvert_{\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]} \equiv 0$.

Comment: You ask good questions Julius

Comment: @DanielFischer Hmmmmm. Is the logic sort of like this: $W$ is the set of all cont. functions on $[0,1]$ that are zero in $[0,1/2]$. Now we have the map $V \to \mathcal C[0,1/2]$, with $f \mapsto f\restriction_{[0, 1/2]}$ Question: What functions get killed? Well, since were just mapping functions to themselves, the ones killed are the ones that are $0$ in $[0, 1/2]$, which is precisely $W$, and the rest is straight-forward. Is this about right? May I finally rejoice? :)

Comment: @Starlight Thanks! I try. I've found that I learn a lot more by first trying a problem myself, really mulling it over, before I ask.:)

Comment: Seems so. Yes, since we're just restricting the functions, the ones that are mapped to $0$ are precisely those that vanish on $\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$, i.e. those in $W$.

Comment: Thank you for your patience with me, the best part about math are those few glimmers of insight after a sweaty thinking session. Now I can sleep comfortably! :)